# Trying to make a loop that asks for a correction when wrong value added

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop, for-in-loop

Im trying to make it so if a value under 50 (LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE) is entered, the loop will ask for the correct amount or continue, right now it simply gets stuck.. any adivce?

```java
package controller;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GoedGoedLauncher {
    final static double LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE = 50.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // 1- prompt the user to input their name and how many orders
        System.out.println("Dit programma is gemaakt door Adzor Verhaagen, MIW - Cohort20, ");
        System.out.print("Voor welke klant wil he de categorie bepalen? ");
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Hoeveel bestellingen moeten er worden ingevoerd? ");
        int numberBestellings = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        //2- make three arrays to hold the bestellingskenmerken(String), totaaledrag (double), bonuspunten(int)
        String[] bestellingsKenmerken = new String[numberBestellings];
        double[] totaalBedrag = new double[numberBestellings];
        int [] bonusPunten = new int[numberBestellings];
        // 3- ask the user for the bestellingskenmerken(int), totaaledrag (double)(not less than 50.0)
        for (int i = 0; i < numberBestellings; i++) {
            System.out.println("Bestelling " + (i + 1));
            System.out.print("\tGeef het kenmerk van de bestelling: ");
            bestellingsKenmerken[i] = input.nextLine();
            do {
                System.out.print("\tGeef het totaalbedrag: ");
                totaalBedrag[i] = input.nextInt();
                input.nextDouble();
                if (totaalBedrag[i] < LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE) {
                    System.out.print("\tFoute invoer! Geef een bedrag van minimaal" + LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE + "euro!\n");
                    System.out.print("\tGeef het totaalbedrag: ");
                    totaalBedrag[i] = input.nextInt();
                }
            } while (totaalBedrag[i] > LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (totaalBedrag[i] > LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE)` it should be negated most likely as you want to keep asking for input for as long as the number is lower than `LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE`. And then you can remove the if statement all along.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the "do-while" esc condition.
You can try this:

```
do {
       System.out.print("\tGeef het totaalbedrag: ");
       totaalBedrag[i] = input.nextInt();
       // Useless row: input.nextDouble();
       if (totaalBedrag[i] < LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE)
            System.out.print("\tFoute invoer! Geef een bedrag van minimaal" + LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE + "euro!\n");

} while (totaalBedrag[i] < LOWEST_ORDER_PRICE);
```

Comment: still gets stuck after the value input, not an error, just nothing happens after i input the value (incorrect or correct )

Comment: Try now. The bug maybe was the useless row "input.nextDouble();".

Comment: So, it works? Let me know and mark the question "resolved" in case, please.